# how to club two cmd commands in command prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to use result of one command in the next command line. Is there any way to do it? preferably in one line. For e.g.

```
1st: where svn; 
2nd: explorer {{result_from_first_cmd}}.
```

I tried `explorer where svn`. Evidently didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FOR` loop. Yeah, it's crazy. It's Windows.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('where svn') DO (explorer "%%~A")
```

Answer (score -1):

Which operating system are you using? Usually you can pipe outputs of one comman line tool to the next one using the | (pipe) operator.

Comment: using windows 10.  I tried running commands with pipe but not expected output. Please help with the example I mentioned in question.
powershell -command `where svn | explorer`
is giving different result than running `where svn` and then `explorer {{copy_pasted_result_of_where_svn}}`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24088750)

Comment: You can’t use a pipe to provide command-line arguments; a pipe connects an output stream (stdout and/or stderr) from one command to the stdin input stream of another.

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko He didn't state his operating system. At this stage it was only possible to provide a general answer since there are a lot of possibilities.

Comment: @SaschaWitte Answers are for answers. No exceptions. Any clarifying questions should be put into the comments. Insufficient reputation is not an excuse.

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko So the solution is not helping? I think revealing the operating system sparked the discussion that lead to the correct answer.